# WebView getUrl() from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview

This is my first app that uses the WebView for my web page.

I want to know how to get the current url from a webview, I'm using this:

```
        SessionDetector session = new SessionDetector(this);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(AppWebViewUrls.getBaseUrl());

    session.start();
```

And this class for get the current url:

```
class SessionDetector extends Thread {
private boolean isLogged = false;
private MainActivity context;

SessionDetector(MainActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!isLogged) {
        if (context.webView.getUrl().contains("cpanel")) {
            isLogged = true;
        }
    }

    context.createMenu();
}
```

}

But, Android throws an exception with the message "All webview methods must be called on the same thread".

I would be glad to know how and why is the cause for this error.

Comment: `why is the cause?` -> `All webview methods must be called on the same thread`

Comment: i.e. you can't call `webView.getUrl()` from `SessionDetector extends Thread`

Comment: So is not possible because is an Android security restriction?

Comment: that's not really the matter. Why do you need to pull constantly the url of the webview? isn't there an event you can catch?

Comment: Thanks for your help njzk2 I found the solution, I was very wrong.

Comment: no there isn't in an SPA @njz

Answer (score -1):

I've found that shouldOverrideUrlLoading method works fine for my case.

```
            @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

            if(url.contains("cpanel")) {
                createMenu();
            }               

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Please remove the call to loadUrl from shouldOverrideUrlLoading. It is not needed and creates a loop.

Comment: @ksasq : since the return value is true, no, it does not create a loop. (but it still stands that this is redundant from the default behavior)

Comment: @njzk2 it will cause another (asynchronous) call to shouldOverrideUrlLoading, which will then call loadUrl, etc.

Comment: I don't think calling `loadUrl` triggers a call to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Comment: @njzk2 - calling loadUrl from shouldOverrideUrlLoading is a bad idea, see what happens if you load a page like this into a webview that does that: http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet